# Amazon Seller Central SP API ERROR - 'code': 'InvalidInput', 'message': 'Invalid request parameters', 'details': ''

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

Updating inventory in the seller central, using their API, suddenly stopped working for Japan and Australia.

I was told by the account holder that Amazon's response to this problem was to just look at the documentation which doesn't help at all since the documentation hasn't changed. The request body that is failing is ...

```
{
    "feedType": "POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA", 
    "inputFeedDocumentId": "[actual document id returned by AWS when document was uploaded]", 
    "path": "/feeds/2021-06-30/feeds", 
    "marketplaceIds": ["A39IBJ37TRP1C6"], 
    "MarketplaceIds": ["A39IBJ37TRP1C6"]
}
```

After editing the `python-amazon-sp-api` library so the request would match the documentation exactly I sent the following request.

```
{
    "feedType": "POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA", 
     "inputFeedDocumentId": "[actual document id returned by AWS when document was uploaded]", 
     "marketplaceIds": ["A39IBJ37TRP1C6"]}'
}
```

The response document for both requests is

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid request parameters",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This response is pretty useless since the details are empty.

The documentation does say to send the file with content type `text/tab-separated-values; charset=iso-8859-1` but when I did that they return an internal error, try again. This problem doesn't happen when I send content type `text/tsv`. Feeds for other countries are still working with this code, but this isn't working with Japan or Australia and Amazon support on this issue is useless! Is there any work-around to get this feed to be accepted by Amazon?

Comment: Did you try with patch method? I was also not able to update with put but with patch it is working.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid It turned out that my problem was that these accounts were deactivated by seller central. Once they were reactivated they started working.

Comment: I already fix this issue most important is XML format in amazon.